# SAMKeychain setPassword is failing

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSLog(@"SETTING VALUE %@", value);
[SAMKeychain setPassword:value forService:SERVICE_NAME account:key];
NSLog(@"READING VALUE %@", [SAMKeychain passwordForService:SERVICE_NAME account:key]);
```

I am always getting (null) after setting a value.
This wasn't happening before I updated XCode.

Does anyone has any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Enable Shared Keychain. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider it marked as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The iOS 10 keychain has been buggy since the early beta of iOS 10. As a (hopefully temporary) workaround, enable the Shared Keychain entitlement in your app. This bug affects every keychain wrapper out there, and not only SAMKeychain.

Comment: Is this kind of thing still happening? SAMKeychain hasn't been updated or had a closed issue for over a year, and I'm wondering about the state of things, or if there's an alternate you'd suggest.